# Is it possible to automatically generate documentation from a transforms repo and reference it in a Rosetta Authoring repository in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I was wondering if there exists a way to automatically generate documentation based on doc-strings in either/both a `Data Transforms` or `Python Library` repository? What I am thinking is ideally a sphinx implementation which builds documentation on for example commits or PR's, and then referencing the documentation somehow from a Rosetta Authoring repository.

Comment: This is possible by modifying the ci build system, but it's too complex and hacky to answer via stackoverflow. Any chance you can reach out via your internal support mechanisms?

Comment: If this is possible, why not add it to the public docs? This is a great feature, if true.